# Django reverse lazy add html anchor?

Tags: django

Im trying to add a html anchor to a django reverse lazy. as such

```
return reverse_lazy("app_settings:index", kwargs={'#branch_device'})
```

however I am receiving the error:

```
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set
```

is adding a anchor this way possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the message says, the error is that you are passing a set as kwargs, instead of a dict.

But even if you fixed that, this cannot work. An anchor is not part of the URL at all and cannot be generated by sending kwargs. You can add it to the generated URL manually, but `reverse_lazy` doesn't return a URL directly. Luckily, there is no reason to use that here rather than `reverse` which returns a URL.

```
return '{}#branch_device'.format(reverse("app_settings:index")
```